# Javascript array to laravel controller

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, laravel

I have an array of users in Javascript and I'm trying to make a post request with that array and some other data to a Laravel controller.

seleccionados = ["A", "B",...]

```
$.post('/guardarOpciones', {
     _token: $('meta[name=csrf-token]').attr('content'),
     equipos: cant_equipos,
     jugadores: cant_jugadores,
     fecha: fecha_inicio,
     users: JSON.stringify(seleccionados)
 }
)
.done(function(data) {
     //alert(data);
})
.fail(function() {
    alert( "error" );
});
```

Now in my controller, im trying to access that array to then loop on it

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Configuracion;

class OpcionesController extends Controller
{
  public function store(Request $request){

    $usuarios = request('users');
    error_log($usuarios);
  }

}
```

Of course $usuarios is a String so I cannot access it as an array, I tried using json_decode and some other things to convert it but didn't work.

What can I do to convert it to an array so I can loop through it? Or maybe I don't have to do JSON.stringify in the ajax post

Comment: remove JSON.stringify() and see if that works?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work.

```
public function store(Request $request){ 
   $usuarios = $request->users; 
}
```

Do not use JSON.stringify.

Comment: Yes, but $usuarios is a string, so if I do $usuarios[0] it returns "["

Answer (score 0):

This should solve your problem (please check comments in lines):

```
public function store(Request $request){ 
    $usersJSON = $request->users; // get your users data
    $usersArray = json_decode($usersJSON, true); // if second parameter is true, you get array, otherwise or if you don't provide it you get object...
    dd($usersArray); // to check your result..
}
```